# clickfunnels - How redirect to different URLs after submitting the form (data have to be saved in Clickfunnels)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect an user to a different page depending on the checkbox he tooked. I tried to use jQuery but the problem is, if i change the href of my button the submit function of cf won't work (saving data in the CF backend).

This is my Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#tmp_button a').on('click', function() {
     var that = this;
     jQuery('.elHeadlineCheckbox').each(function(i, e) {
       if(
         jQuery(this).attr('data-custom-type') == 'my-checkbox' &&
         jQuery(this).attr('value') != 'false'
         ) {
           jQuery(that).attr('href', 'https://page1.com');
       } else if (
         jQuery(this).attr('data-custom-type') == 'my-checkbox' &&
         jQuery(this).attr('value') == 'false'
       ) {
             jQuery(that).attr('href', 'https://page1.com');
       }
     })
   });
 });
```

Comment: May you post the hml with the form ?

Comment: If you don't use Ajax to post data to the second page and the first page is really submitting and redirecting to a new url, then yuo have to handle the final target page in the second page not in this page.

Comment: and how could I send the data via ajax to page two, so that cf can save them?